# .Replace() will return empty string inside my Powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, pnp-powershell, powershell-script

I have the following PnP PowerShell to get the URL of a file and remove the ".lock" string from the file name using `Replace`:-

```
$url = $item.File.ServerRelativeUrl
Write-Host "$(Get-Date) - ($($Counter)/$($AllItems.Count)) - Restoring version $VersionLabel for $($Item.File.Name)"
$item.File.Versions.RestoreByLabel($VersionLabel)
Invoke-PnPQuery
                
$restoedFile = Get-PnPFile -Url $url 
Write-Host "2) -->"
            
url2 = $url.Replace(".lock","")
Write-Host "1) $url" $url
Write-Host "3) $url2" $url2
```

But this code `url2 = $url.Replace(".lock","")` will return empty string. Any advice?

Comment: In line `url2 = $url.Replace(".lock","")` in this line I cannot see $ for variable `url2`.  It may be throwing exception.  It should be `$url2 = $url.Replace(".lock","")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code which will get the files and then get each file name without extension:

```
$LibraryName = "Documents"
$LibraryItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $LibraryName -PageSize 500 -Fields "FileLeafRef" | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"} 

#Get File count
Write-Host "Total Number of Items Found:"$LibraryItems.count 

#Get each File name
ForEach($Item in $LibraryItems)
{
    $FileNameWithExtension = $Item.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"] 
    $FileNameWithOutExtension = $FileNameWithExtension.Substring(0, $FileNameWithExtension.LastIndexOf("."))
    Write-Host $FileNameWithOutExtension    
}
```